# Function declaring object and returning it

Tags: javascript

Every time I write a function whose sole purpose is to return a configuration object I write it like this:

```
function getConfig() {
  return {
    bar: 'bar',
    foo: 'foo'
  }
}
```

Seems logical right? If I later want to add properties I just add them directly inside of the object literal. If I want to add functions, I add their references inside the object literal with a matching function declaration in `getConfig`:

```
function getConfig() {
  return {
    bar: 'bar',
    foo: 'foo',
    getBaz: getBaz
  }

  function getBaz() {
     //get baz
  }
}
```

However, alot of times when I look at other people's code I see functions with a similar purpose but they frequently first declare the object and then just return the object reference:

```
function getConfig() {
  var config = {
    bar: 'bar',
    foo: 'foo'
  }
  return config;
}
```

Is there some sort of performance improvement or other "trick" I'm missing here? Surely the people who wrote these functions must realize it would be easier and more readable to just return the object literal.

Comment: Maybe it's easier and more readable *to them* to store the object in a local variable. Who knows?

Comment: Maybe sometimes you want to make some transformation to the object you're going to return, but you can't do that if you return it right away... see what I mean? I don't think it makes any difference anyway in terms of performance or readability.

Comment: Just wanted to add that the structure you are using is called a `closure` in Javascript. In the [Mozilla documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Closures) they return the object literal. I think it is just a matter of taste.

Comment: Its just a preference, i don't see any difference in both the examples you have provided.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your stripped-down examples there is really no difference. But there are cases when it makes sense to declare an object variable and then return that.

For example, if you want to create a hash it's good practice to create an object with a null prototype:

```
function getConfig() {
  var config = Object.create(null);
  config.bar = 'bar';
  config.foo = 'foo';

  return config;
}
```

There is also the question of readability. If the object you're creating has many levels of nested hierarchy, an object literal may become confusing to read.

Let's also consider debugging. What if your property assignments are expressions that may fail? If you create an object and then do your assignments each on its own line, you can very quickly determine the problem.

Finally, different coders have different preferences. Unless your organization has a style guide, there is going to be a difference of opinion on things like this—and probably even if it *does* have a style guide.

Comment: I don't see any difference either... its just readability in total...